# How to assert a partial match with stretchr/testify/mock AssertCalled?

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, testify

Consider this unit test file in Go.  I'm using [`github.com/stretchr/testify/mock`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock) package.

```golang
type Person struct {Name string; Age int}
type Doer struct { mock.Mock }

func (d *Doer) doWithThing(arg Person) {
    fmt.Printf("doWithThing %v\n", arg)
    d.Called(arg)
}

func TestDoer(t *testing.T) {
    d := new(Doer)
    d.On("doWithThing", mock.Anything).Return()
    d.doWithThing(Person{Name: "John", Age: 7})
    
    // I don't care what Age was passed. Only Name
    d.AssertCalled(t, "doWithThing", Person{Name: "John"})
}
```

This tests fails because `testify` uses `Age: 0` in the comparison when I don't pass an age.  I get that, but I'm wondering, how do I assert against a partial of the argument that was passed?  I want this test to pass whatever `Age` is, so long as `Name = John`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`mock.MatchedBy`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock#MatchedBy).

In short, it wraps an arbitrary matcher function with a `mock.argumentMatcher` (unexported):

> argumentMatcher performs custom argument matching, returning whether or not the argument is matched by the expectation fixture function.

In particular, the argument of `mock.MatchedBy` is:

> [...] a function accepting a single argument (of the expected type) which returns a bool

So you can use it as follows:

```
personNameMatcher := mock.MatchedBy(func(p Person) bool {
    return p.Name == "John"
})
d.AssertCalled(t, "doWithThing", personNameMatcher)
```

Comment: I just want to add that you can also use these in your expectations, e.g. `d.On("doWithThing", personNameMatcher)`.

Comment: For some reason it fails for me. It is comparing function to an object.